# StoreFront Footer Credits Line

Tags: css, wordpress, storefront

I was looking for some advice on how I can change the footer line where the footer credits are shown.

At present, I have been able to activate footer-1, footer-2, footer-3, footer-4 above the footer credit line and this all shows up fine.

What I am trying to do now is to split the footer credit line into 2 columns, on the left hand side where i have the footer credits and on the right hand side i would like to show what payment methods are accepted.

I have created a child theme and copied the footer.php file from themes\store-front\inc\structure but not sure how i go about doing this.

If possible I would also like to know how i can change the color of the background where the footer credit is, at the moment it all looks it sits within 1 div class.

My current HTML code (Firebug) shows what I currently have:

```
<footer id="colophon" class="site-footer" role="contentinfo">
    <div class="col-full">
        <section class="footer-widgets col-4 fix">
            <section class="block footer-widget-1">
                <aside id="text-2" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-last widget-odd widget widget_text">
                    <h3>Get In Touch</h3>
                    <div class="textwidget">
                        My Site Ltd<br>
                        01234 567 8901<br>
                        info@mysite.com<br>
                        Email Us Today and we will respond within 24 hours!<br>
                    </div>
                </aside>
            </section>
            <section class="block footer-widget-2">
                <aside id="pages-2" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-last widget-odd widget widget_pages">
                    <h3>ABOUT MYSITE</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-101"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-5"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/cart/">Cart</a></li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/checkout/">Checkout</a></li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-81 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/">Home</a></li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-7"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/my-account/">My Account</a></li>
                        <li class="page_item page-item-4"><a href="http://localhost/mysite/shop/">Shop</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
            </section>
            <section class="block footer-widget-3">
                <aside id="text-5" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-last widget-odd widget widget_text">
                    <h3>WHERE CAN I SEE YOU</h3>
                    <div class="textwidget">JFKLSDJKFJDSJL</div>
                </aside>
            </section>
            <section class="block footer-widget-4">
                <aside id="text-6" class="widget-1 widget-first widget-last widget-odd widget widget_text">
                    <h3>SIGN UP FOR GREAT OFFERS</h3>
                    <div class="textwidget">Be the first in line to receive our great new offers directly into your inbox!</div>
                </aside>
            </section>
        </section><!-- /.footer-widgets  -->
        <div class="site-info">
            © My Site 2015
        </div><!-- .site-info -->
    </div><!-- .col-full -->
</footer>
```

Apologies as made an error as forgot to paste my code or demo to demonstrate what I currently have.

Comment: Welcome Michael, You can receive help from here if you can post your code + demo instead of explaining it theoretically.

Answer (score 0):

As told by my web host TNP HOST ,

Install Plugin : Custom CSS

and then add following lines to custom css

```
.site-info {
display: none;}
```

Comment: Ok will give this a go. Thanks

Comment: Hi, ankur any chance you have a link for the custom css plugin?

Comment: Try google "custom css wordpress" and there you get first link at top !  I think i dont have permission to post link here

Answer (score 0):

I created a WordPress plugin to remove the WooCommerce StoreFront theme footer credit so you don't have to modify code [here](https://upwerd.com/remove-woocommerce-footer-credit/).